# Ncurses bug mouse coordinates to beyond 222 width or height terminal

Tags: c, events, mouse, ncurses, curses

I am coding an user interface with ncurses.
I have a problem when my terminal width or height is beyond to 222 characters/rows, mouses coordinates return the -33 value, so when i click to beyond 222 characters mouse_x = -33
when i click to beyond 222 rows mouse_y = -33

Would it be possible to tell ncurses no to stop mouses events beyond 222 characters/rows ?
This bug also occurs in vim, when you move the :vs separation bar beyond 222 characters, it goes back to x=0.

Maybe this bug has already been fixed ?

```
  1 #include <ncurses.h>
  2 
  3 void    treat_mouse(MEVENT* event);
  4 
  5 int     main(void)
  6 {
  7         bool    run;
  8         int     key;
  9         MEVENT  event;
 10 
 11         run = true;
 12         initscr();
 13         noecho();
 14         keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
 15         mousemask(BUTTON1_PRESSED, NULL);
 16         while (run == true)
 17         {
 18                 key = getch();
 19                 switch  (key)
 20                 {
 21                         case    'q':
 22                                 run = false;
 23                                 break;
 24                         case    KEY_MOUSE:
 25                                 treat_mouse(&event);
 26                                 break;
 27                         default:
 28                                 break;
 29                 }
 30         }
 31         endwin();
 32         return 0;
 33 }
 34 
 35 void    treat_mouse(MEVENT* event)
 36 {
 37         if (getmouse(event) == OK)
 38                 mvwprintw(stdscr, 0, 0, "click: x = %d, y = %d\n", event->x, event->y);
 39 }
```

.

.

========================    EDIT   =======================

.

.

Ok i have found.

I have downloaded ncurses code source here **http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/**

And i have taken this link **ncurses-5.9.tar.gz      04-Apr-2011 19:12  2.7M**

I have searched **getch()**.

**getch()** call **wgetch()**.

**wgetch()** call **_nc_wgetch()**.

**_nc_wgetch()** call **_mouse_inline()**.

**_mouse_inline()** is a function pointer in **struct screen** who call **_nc_mouse_inline()** or **no_mouse_inline()** who is an empty function (when no mouse i think).

you can see **_nc_mouse_inline()** function in **ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/lib_mouse.c**

She use **unsigned char** to calcul mouse coordinates, to see this litle example:

```
821 static bool
822 _nc_mouse_inline(SCREEN *sp)
823 /* mouse report received in the keyboard stream -- parse its info */
824 {
.
.
.
832         unsigned char kbuf[4];
.
.
.
970         eventp->x = (kbuf[1] - ' ') - 1;
971         eventp->y = (kbuf[2] - ' ') - 1;
.
.
.
984     return (result);
985 }
```

Finally I'll do anything.

Comment: This answers your question: [How to Build Curses Program That Supports More Than 223 Columns of Mouse Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256750/how-to-build-curses-program-that-supports-more-than-223-columns-of-mouse-input)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've found the answer to your question.

```
unsigned char kbuf[4];
eventp->x = (kbuf[1] - ' ') - 1;
eventp->y = (kbuf[2] - ' ') - 1;
```

The mouse x and y are been received as `unsigned char`, so the maximum value they can hold is 255. `' '` (space) is ASCII 32, so the maximum value possible is `255 - 32 - 1` which equals 222.

The value then wraps to 0 giving `0 - 32 -1` which equals -33.

Comment: This is a limitation of the xterm mouse protocol. There is an extension (SGR 1006), but the latest news about its support in ncurses were just: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2013-01/msg00014.html